# Python speech recognition no reconoce mi micrófono

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un asistente de voz en Python usando la librería speech recognition y pyttsx3, pero a la hora de intentar decirle algo, no me detecta mi micrófono:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

listener = sr.Recognizer()

try:
    with sr.microphone() as source:
        print('Escuchando...') 
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
except:
    print('A ocurrido un error')
```

A la hora de ejecutar el programa no me salta ningún error en la consola. También he comprobado la configuración del micro en mi equipo y esta activado, ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

quizas sea muy tarde mi respuesta, pero me pasaba lo mismo, estaba buscando por todo lado y no encontre solucion en internet. Hasta que  me di cuenta que esto pasa por que el microfono se queda escuchando por los ruidos internos que genera tu pc, mi solucion fue ir a ajusted de microfono y habilitar el modo de supresion de ruidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si no viene esas opciones en tu pc, solo tienes que buscar el controlador segun la marca de tu pc y descargar la ultima version. ya que casi siempre viene controladores antiguos que por algun modo tampoco lo actualiza el update de windows. lo tienes que buscar en la pagina de tu proveedor.